# Magento 2 Rest API response "There is no mediagalleryentryconverter for given type". How fix it?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, postman, get

I need to get All Products using Magento 2 Rest API, but on some products I get response: "There is no mediagalleryentryconverter for given type".
How can I fix it? I use POSTMAN for testing.

**My request string:  GET /rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=100**

My Header:

**Authorization : Bearer**

**Content-Type : application/xml;**

**Accept : application/xml**

Maybe I need to use some additional parameter in the hader????

Comment: hi there, i am not sure what's causing this behavior, the above mentioned call works for me with the same headers. is it possible that you have a 3rd party module interfering with this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

This is a standard request and the correct answer comes to 1400 records. 
But only to 1401 and 1402 I have receive:"There is no mediagalleryentryconverter for given type".
I think this is due to the types of images that are loaded into this product to Magento2.
I cann't get 1401 and 1402 products. response"There is no mediagalleryentryconverter for given type".
I cann't uderstand how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and found some similar complaints about the same error (maybe you found them too already), but in different contexts:

[How to attach an image for a product using magento2 REST API?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170467/how-to-attach-an-image-for-a-product-using-magento2-rest-api)
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1417
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072829/magento-2-02-soap-api-c-sharp-uploading-images-error

So there is the question about the image type that is being registered in Magento and this is where I would start from. Check what happens if you remove the images and re-upload them, query the database, see what differs from regular products.